# Access Redux State Object Property in Function

Tags: function, reactjs, state, redux

I have an inline function in my react component set up like this:

```
render() {
    const { post } = this.props;

    return (
        <div>
            {function(){
                if ({post}) {
                    return <h1>Post name exists {post.name}</h1>
                } else {
                    return <h1> Post name does not exist</h1>
                }
            }.call(this)}
     .....
```

and I have redux state set up like this:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { 
        post:state.post.single,
    };
}
```

The above code works, but what I really want to check is if post.name is null or not, in which case I render different things on the page. However, I keep getting an error when I do this:

```
if({post.name})
```

Comment: @AvraamMavridis is says that the "." in {post.name} is an unexpected token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it WORKING by calling the function instead of doing an inline call:

```
renderCheck(){
    if(this.props.post.name){
      return (
        <div>
          ....
        </div>
      )
    }
 }
```

In the render I called it like this:

```
 {this.renderCheck()}
```

I'm still unsure why const { post : { name } } = this.props; didn't work but I will be using this for now.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to extract value of object inside of an `if`, you can't do that, e.g.:

```
function something(post){
  if({ post.name })
  {

  }

}
```

or even

```
function something(post){
  if({ post})
  {

  }

}
```

Is not valid js, you can check it in [babel repl](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Ces2015-loose%2Creact%2Cstage-0%2Cstage-1%2Cstage-2%2Cstage-3&code=function%20something(t)%7B%0A%20%20if(%7B%20t.name%20%7D)%0A%20%20%7B%7D%0A%20%20%0A%7D)

What you can do is

```
const { post : { name } } = this.props;
```

And then check with `if(name)`

Comment: Thanks I tried this approach but I got an error of: Cannot read property 'name' of null

Comment: @lost9123193 so there is something wrong with your mapping, you dont pass the state to the component. are you using `connect` and a selector?

Comment: Ah see. I believe it's connected because I'm able to do this inside the render method:  <h1>{post.name}</h1>  What would I use the selector for?

Comment: I can't see from your code how is able to do `post.name` and on the same time have `Cannot read property 'name' of null` when you do `const { post : { name } } = this.props;`

Comment: I'm not sure either but I tried something else and got it working. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1):

Hi use a renderCheck function is a good approach if you have to do some test. But you have to do a double check props.post and props.post.name :(
To avoid this "nested" checks I'm using ImmutableJS, then in my connect I would have

```
name: state.getIn(['post'], ['name'])
```

That will return undefined either post or name is undefined or null :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Would I put this in the renderCheck function?

Comment: If your state is Immutable friendly you can have this directly in the connect, I think like this:


`    function mapStateToProps(state) {
        return { 
            postName: state.getIn(['post', 'single', 'name']),
        };
    }
`